# How to find the matching bracket at a point in elisp?

Tags: syntax, balanced-parentheses, delimiters

What is a reliable way to find the matching balanced bracket (eg: `{}`, `[]`, `()` in C or Python), which doesn't get confused by brackets in strings, or escaped brackets for e.g.

Example:

```
["Foo]" ?\] 0 [1 2]]
^                  ^
Input point.      Return point.
```

Something like how `show-paren-mode` works, except as an elisp-function where you can pass in a point and get a matching point or `nil` when not found.

Answer (score 1):

Generally `forward-sexp` should know what to do in any given mode, so you could perhaps base it on this:

```el
(save-excursion (ignore-errors (forward-sexp) (1- (point))))
```

Alternatively...

> Something like how `show-paren-mode` works

You could use that exact same code.  Look at <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-function` <kbd>RET</kbd> `show-paren-function` and how it uses the results of `(funcall show-paren-data-function)`, and adapt to your purposes.

```
show-paren-data-function is a variable defined in `paren.el'.
Its value is `show-paren--default'

  This variable may be risky if used as a file-local variable.

Documentation:
Function to find the opener/closer "near" point and its match.
The function is called with no argument and should return either nil
if there's no opener/closer near point, or a list of the form
(HERE-BEG HERE-END THERE-BEG THERE-END MISMATCH)
Where HERE-BEG..HERE-END is expected to be near point.
```